# What is the resistivity of copper at 3 kelvin?

Tags: electrical-resistance

I couldn't find the value of resistivity of copper at 2.73K on google

Comment: Strongly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241274/

Comment: I wanted to know the value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a problem with answering your question in that at such a low temperature the resistivity of copper is very much determined by the impurities and crystallographic defects eg dislocations, voids etc, which may be present.
At low temperatures it is the scattering of free electrons by impurities and crystallographic defects which determine the resistivity rather than the thermal excitation of the copper ions.

The parameter which is often measured is the residual resistance ratio $\dfrac{R_{\text{273  K}}}{R_{4.2\,\rm K}}$ which for fairly pure copper wire as used for telephone lines might be of the order of $100$.

Large single crystals of very pure copper can be produced with residual resistance ratios in the thousands.

[image].

I have annotated the graph to illustrate the non-linear logarithmic scale and how to find the resistivity of copper at $3\, \rm K$.

[image]

Comment: so it's impossible to use copper at any temperature around 3k as a conductor

Comment: @AJK That is not what I wrote.  From the graph you can get an estimate of the resistivity of “ordinary” copper at around $3\,\rm K$. At this temperature the copper is a much better conductor of electricity than at room temperature.

Comment: How do we get the estimate

Comment: @AJK From the graph noting that it is a log-log graph.

Comment: I have no clue what that means

Comment: Did you mean that it's has a very low resistivity

Comment: @AJK Yes, it is a much better conductor at low temperatures.

Comment: Do you know what a logarithmic axis is? Both axes in the graph are logarithmic, which makes it “log-log”.

Comment: Where did you find this graph? I never saw a log scale with 3/30/300 as its 'major' tics before. Sure it works, but - WHY?

Comment: @asdfex probably because there's no data for <=3 so it would just be a huge waste of space

Comment: @asdfex The graph was [slide 28](https://indico.cern.ch/event/194284/contributions/1472798/attachments/281498/393574/CAS_propmat_2013.pdf) from a set of slides produced by CERN

Comment: All SE posts are version controlled, so please [do not make your post look like a revision table](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/25301), instead just seamlessly integrate the new material into the post. There is an edit history button at the bottom of the post for those interested in seeing what changed.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for the reply. I will amend my answers as I come across them.